# transposing mysql temporary table rows to columns

Tags: mysql

I would like to transpose this table

```
A  |  B  |  C
----------------
1  |  10 | "XXX"
1  |  20 | "YYY"
2  |  40 | "XXX"
2  |  50 | "YYY"
3  |  10 | "XXX"
3  |  20 | "YYY"
3  |  60 | "ZZZ"
```

to this:

```
A  | XXX | YYY | ZZZ |
----------------------
1  |  10 | 20  |  0  |
2  |  40 | 50  |  0  |
3  |  10 | 20  | 60  |
```

I can only use temporary table and I've read in the help that self-referencing does not work.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html 
Any help?

Comment: This is called pivoting.  Google "mysql pivoting" if you know the columns you want.  Google "mysql dynamic pivoting" if the columns are based on the values in the column.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the values in `column C`, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select A, 
       coalesce(max(case when c = 'XXX' then B end),0) XXX,
       coalesce(max(case when c = 'YYY' then B end),0) YYY,
       coalesce(max(case when c = 'ZZZ' then B end),0) ZZZ
from yourtable
group by A
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d521/3)

If not and you don't know the number of potential columns, then you'll need to use `dynamic sql`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I got the result of only 1 value in each row.

Comment: @sievy -- did you review the fiddle?  Given your sample input, it produces your desired results.

Comment: You're right. I checked it and it worked fine. Thanks